TLS and Oracle API for MongoDB
I'm using the Oracle API for MongoDB with Oracle REST Data Services as described here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/24.3/ordig/oracle-api-mongodb-support.html
By default, this installation uses a self-signed certificate that expires after a couple weeks.  I'd like to avoid this expiration and avoid the "self signed certificate" warning from my Java client.

Here are the steps for generating and signing your own certificate.
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private.key -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 
openssl req -new -key private.key -out csr.csr 
openssl x509 -req -in csr.csr -signkey private.key -out certificate.crt -days 365


Then, in ORDS settings config/global/settings.xml add these lines:
<entry key="standalone.https.cert">/path/to/certificate.crt/</entry> 
<entry key="standalone.https.cert.key">/path/to/private.key/</entry>

Create a truststore for your Java client:
keytool -keystore truststore.jks -alias test -import -file certificate.crt

Set these Java properties when you start the application
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=passwordHere 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/truststore.jks

